# Can't link with Xerces-c static library with g++

Tags: c++, g++, xerces, libtool, xerces-c

I downloaded and unpacked `xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4.tar.gz`, 
So I have

```
$ ls -1 /users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/lib
libxerces-c-3.1.so
libxerces-c.a
libxerces-c.la
libxerces-c.so
pkgconfig
```

Then I have my `Makefile` as

```
CC := gcc
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -O3
LDFLAGS := -O3

CXXFLAGS += -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include
CXXFLAGS += -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY
LDFLAGS += -L/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/lib
LDFLAGS += -Bstatic
LDFLAGS += -lxerces-c

ReadXML: DOM.o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyXMLString.o ReadXML.o

clean:
    @rm -rvf *.o ReadXML
```

The `make` command works fine.

```
$ make -B
g++ -O3 -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY   -c -o ReadXML.o ReadXML.cpp
g++ -O3 -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY   -c -o DOM.o DOM.cpp
g++ -O3 -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY   -c -o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyDOMErrorHandler.cpp
g++ -O3 -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY   -c -o MyXMLString.o MyXMLString.cpp
gcc -O3 -L/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/lib -Bstatic -lxerces-c  ReadXML.o DOM.o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyXMLString.o   -o ReadXML
```

But the result executable `ReadXML` is not as "static" as I hope it to be. It prints

```
./ReadXML: error while loading shared libraries: libxerces-c-3.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

until I `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/lib`. Obviously, the xerces-c is linked dynamically.

Why the `-Bstatic` doesn't help me to create a static linked executable?

---

Update 2013.05.13

Followed @n.m. 's advise and got error like

```
 gcc -O3 -L/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lxerces-c  ReadXML.o DOM.o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyXMLString.o   -o ReadXML
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ReadXML] Error 1
```

And with `LDFLAGS +=  -Wl,-Bstatic -lxerces-c -Wl,-Bdynamic`, I got

```
g++ -O3 -L/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lxerces-c -Wl,-Bdynamic -o ReadXML DOM.o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyXMLString.o ReadXML.o
DOM.o: In function `parseXMLFile(char const*)':
DOM.cpp:(.text+0x3a6): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(unsigned short const*)'
DOM.cpp:(.text+0x3b3): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'
DOM.cpp:(.text+0x3dc): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesHandleMultipleImports'
DOM.cpp:(.text+0x3f0): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesSchema'
DOM.cpp:(.text+0x404): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaFullChecking'
DOM.cpp:(.text+0x42f): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMErrorHandler'
... # Many other lines
ReadXML.cpp:(.text+0x1eb): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(char**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'
ReadXML.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x28): undefined reference to `typeinfo for xercesc_3_1::XMLException'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ReadXML] Error 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `-Wl,-Bstatic` instead of just `-Bstatic`. Also use `-v` to look at the exact options g++ is passing to the linker.

Comment: More precisely, say `-Wl,-Bstatic -lxerces-c -Wl,-Bdynamic` if you want just that library to be linked statically. Not all systems will support static linking to *all* of the system libraries.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for your answer. Will try it at Monday. BTW, why not post an answer for this?

Comment: @n.m. Sorry. Got error. Updating the question.

Comment: You haven't read the second comment...

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for your reply. You see in the command, I have no more external libraries to link, so I omitted the option by intention. Just now I tried `-Wl,-Bstatic -lxerces-c -Wl,-Bdynami` and got lots of errors that was beyond my understanding. Updating the question.

Comment: You switched from linking with g++ to linking with gcc. That's the error. Switch back. Gcc doesn't know about C++ libraries.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. I don't think it's the real cause. You see I built the dynamic version with gcc successfully. Weird. Anyway, I now force the `make` to use `g++` and the error now only focuses on xerces-c . Question updated.

Comment: You also have to move all .o files in front of all .a and .so files in your link command. Hope it's the last problem here...

Comment: @n.m. Unfortunately, it's not. I fixed it finally and post the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for @n.m. 's help. I got the answer after studying a little from `libtool`. Let me post the answer here.

Finally my working `Makefile` looks like

```
CC := gcc
CXX := g++
LD := g++
CXXFLAGS := -O3
LDFLAGS := -O3

CXXFLAGS += -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include
CXXFLAGS += -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY
LDFLAGS += -L/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/lib

ReadXML: DOM.o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyXMLString.o ReadXML.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -Wl,-Bstatic -lxerces-c -Wl,-Bdynamic -lnsl -lpthread -lcurl
test: ReadXML
    ldd $(abspath $<)
    $(abspath $<) /users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/samples/data/personal.xml
```

And then the result comes as

```
$ make -B ReadXML
g++ -O3 -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY   -c -o DOM.o DOM.cpp
g++ -O3 -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY   -c -o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyDOMErrorHandler.cpp
g++ -O3 -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY   -c -o MyXMLString.o MyXMLString.cpp
g++ -O3 -I/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86_64-linux-gcc-3.4/include -DXERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY   -c -o ReadXML.o ReadXML.cpp
g++ -O3 -L/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/lib -o ReadXML DOM.o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyXMLString.o ReadXML.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lxerces-c -Wl,-Bdynamic -lnsl -lpthread -lcurl
```

and

```
$ make test
ldd /users/jdyu/labs/xerces/ReadXML/ReadXML
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6fdd6000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x0000003b5e200000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003b4ea00000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x0000003b5f200000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003b54e00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003b4e200000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003b54200000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003b4de00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003b4d600000)
    libidn.so.11 => /lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x0000003b5d200000)
    libldap-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x0000003b60000000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003b4f200000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x0000003b56a00000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000003b55e00000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000003b56600000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000003b55600000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003b4ee00000)
    libssl3.so => /usr/lib64/libssl3.so (0x0000003b61000000)
    libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x0000003b60800000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x0000003b5ea00000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x0000003b60400000)
    libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x0000003b5ca00000)
    libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x0000003b5c600000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x0000003b5e600000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003b4e600000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x0000003b5de00000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x0000003b5fc00000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000003b4fa00000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x0000003b5f800000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x0000003b57a00000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x0000003b55200000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x0000003b55a00000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x0000003b56200000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x0000003b5d600000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000003b4f600000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x0000003b5da00000)
/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/ReadXML/ReadXML /users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/samples/data/personal.xml
Parsing XML file '/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/samples/data/personal.xml' ...
Parsing finished in 1 millisecond(s).
37 nodes found.
XML platform terminated successfully!
```

The `xerces-c` linked statically.

---

And `libtool` can make it even more static. Append the make file with

```
ReadXML_: DOM.o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyXMLString.o ReadXML.o
    libtool --tag=CXX --mode=link $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -lxerces-c -lnsl -lpthread -lcurl
test_: ReadXML_
    -ldd $(abspath $<)
    $(abspath $<) /users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/samples/data/personal.xml
```

and got the result

```
$ make ReadXML_
libtool --tag=CXX --mode=link g++ -O3 -L/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/lib -o ReadXML_ DOM.o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyXMLString.o ReadXML.o -lxerces-c -lnsl -lpthread -lcurl
libtool: link: g++ -O3 -o .libs/ReadXML_ DOM.o MyDOMErrorHandler.o MyXMLString.o ReadXML.o  -L/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/lib /users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/lib/libxerces-c.so -lnsl -lpthread -lcurl -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
```

and

```
$ make test_
ldd /users/jdyu/labs/xerces/ReadXML/ReadXML_
    not a dynamic executable
make: [test_] Error 1 (ignored)
/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/ReadXML/ReadXML_ /users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/samples/data/personal.xml
Parsing XML file '/users/jdyu/labs/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/samples/data/personal.xml' ...
Parsing finished in 1 millisecond(s).
37 nodes found.
XML platform terminated successfully!
```

---

There is far more in the `libtool` to learn for me. I tried hard reading `libtool` code, only to failed to figure out how it coverts the temporary dynamic `.libs/ReadXML_` to the final `ReadXML_` which is totally static linked.
Anyway, the answer of this question is found.

Thanks again, @n.m.